# Getting multiple values

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried to get multiple numeric values which is inside

```
<li> <div class ="kpi unit">
```

I have tried this:

```
def get_all_data(self):
    data = []
    for row in self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("content"):
        cells = []
        for cell in row.find_elements_by_class_name('kpi unit'):
            cells.append(cell.text)
        data.append(cells)
```

I'm getting error as class name cant be used, tried all other stuff and  unable to get the values..
Any suggestions?

please find my html code below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
      <section class="section active" style="padding-top: 38px;">
         <p class="title" style="left: 0px;">
         <a id="summary" href="#summarystats">Summary</a>
         </p>
         <div class="content" data-slug="summarystats">
            <div class="row data-card summary-card">
            <ul class="small-block-grid-4">
               <li>
                   <div class="kpi stat">Impressions</div>
                   <div class="kpi unit" data-bind="text: kpis.impressions.slice">0</div>
              </li> 
              <li>
                   <div class="kpi stat">Clicks</div>
                   <div class="kpi unit" data-bind="text: kpis.clicks.slice">0</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                   <div class="kpi stat">Spent</div>
                   <div class="kpi unit" data-bind="text: kpis.spent.slice">$0</div>
              </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"find_elements_by_class_name" is searching by a single class name. In your case when you have two of them, ou should use css selector or xpath. For example:

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".kpi.unit");
```

Comment: Nice, It worked with css selector, using find_elements_by_css_selector(".kpi.unit") ..., My approach was huge, I nested other class names to get the list, instead of one single direct approach, thanks